# Output truncated using scala.sys.process and ByteArrayOutputStream

Tags: scala, concurrency, io

I'm want to run a command and get the output without intermediary files. It generally works but will truncate the output sometimes.

For instance, if I run this program that will generate always the same output and count the number of bytes on it:

```
object BugTest extends App {

  import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream

  import scala.language.postfixOps
  import scala.sys.process._

  def run(): Array[Byte] = {
    val os = new ByteArrayOutputStream()
    val stderr = new StringBuilder
    val processLogger = ProcessLogger(x => stderr.append(x + "\n"), x => stderr.append(x + "\n"))
    val code = Seq("seq", "10000") #> os ! processLogger
    if (code != 0)
      throw new Exception(s"Got code $code: ${stderr.mkString}")
    os.close()
    os.toByteArray
  }

  val reference = run().size
  println(reference)
  var current = 0
  do {
    current = run().size
    println(current)
  } while (current == reference)
}
```

It will randomly fail with a output that is smaller than the right one. Example of execution:

```
48894
48894
48894
48894
48894
48894
48894
48894
48894
48128 <-- Truncated output !?
```

What am I doing wrong?

Note: tested on Scala 2.12.6

Update:

This code seems to work without any issues (i.e it keeps looping forever printing 48894):

```
object BugTest extends App {

  import java.io._

  import scala.language.postfixOps
  import scala.sys.process._

  def outputProcessIO(stdout: OutputStream, stderr: OutputStream): ProcessIO = {
    new ProcessIO(
      _.close(),
     (is: InputStream) => BasicIO.transferFully(is, stdout),
     (is: InputStream) => BasicIO.transferFully(is, stderr)
    )
  }
  def run(): Array[Byte] = {
    val stdout = new ByteArrayOutputStream()
    val stderr = new ByteArrayOutputStream()
    val p = Seq("seq", "10000") run outputProcessIO(stdout, stderr)
    if (p.exitValue() != 0)
      throw new Exception(s"Got code $p: ${new String(stderr.toByteArray)}")
    stdout.toByteArray
  }

  val reference = run().size
  println(reference)
  var current = 0
  do {
    current = run().size
    println(current)
  } while (current == reference)
}
```

I still would like to know what's the problem with the original code.

Comment: I'm confused. Isn't that last bit an infinite loop?

Comment: @erip If everything works deterministically, yes. But sometimes it randomly returns a different result. This is the strange behavior I'm trying to figure out.

Comment: Since you're stopping after the 1st "truncation," do you know for certain that there is any data loss? Might the next iteration pick up where the last left off?

Comment: @jwvh The iterations should be independent. The loop is just a fast way to reproduce the problem. If the result in the iteration is smaller than usual, then something was lost.

Comment: The first example works as expected for me on MacOS.

Comment: @som-snytt I can reproduce in on both Ubuntu desktop and server. It would be interesting if it's OS/Java version specific

Comment: Indeed at the office, it terminates in a second or two on Ubuntu. Suspiciously, also with 48128. I once briefly understood the process code. I think the first example is kicking off more threads to copy in/out the process objects, which may/may not matter.